# How to update HTML UI while in a JS loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, user-interface

Here I am trying to update a progress bar based on the progress through the loop, but the bar doesn't update until nested loop is through, which is not ideal.

```
function upload_img() {
    // Actual progress bar
    progress_bar = document.querySelector("#progress-bar");
    document.querySelector("#bar-area").style.display = "flex";

    //**Omitted

    setTimeout(function() {
        //**Omitted

        let size = obj_data.length * obj_data[0].length;

        for (let row = 0; row < obj_data.length; row++) {
            for (let col = 0; col < obj_data[0].length; col++) {
                // Incrementing counter
                j++;

                if (j % 1000 === 0 || j === size) {
                    //Should be updating progress bar every 1000 out of 13400, but is not doing so until end^^^^
                    progress_bar.style.width = `${Math.round(j / size * 100)}%`;
                    console.log(`${j} of ${size} so percent is ${j / size * 100}`)
                }

                   
            }

        }

    }, 1)

}
```

I tried to use intervals/timeouts, but they didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often find it easier to work with *async/await* than *setTimeout/setInterval* etc. Then all you would have to do is sleep/wait/pause for a number of ms between each loop iteration (which gives the browser time to rerender the screen, because it doesn't do that if you don't pause the script).

If only JavaScript had a sleep function... Well actually you can write a sleep function in one line of code: Receive a number of milliseconds, create a **promise** that will resolve after that number of milliseconds, and use *setTimeout* once inside this function to make that happen.

Since using **await** is waiting for a **promise** to resolve you can then do **await sleep(ms)** inside your loop (as long as it inside a **async** function - a function where **await** is allowed).

The implementation of a progress bar below is based on this idea and allows you to update the progress bar inside a loop, as you wanted.

Of course you can do other things inside that loop to (or call a function that does other things) - like uploading things, fetching things etc. But in this example I focused on the progress bar and that you can update it inside a loop.

```js
async function progressBarExample() {
  const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
  const pBarEl = document.querySelector('.progress-bar div');
  const pBarTextEl = document.querySelector('.progress-bar span');
  const loopMax = 1000;
  for (let i = 0; i < loopMax; i++) {
    let percent = (i / loopMax) * 100;
    pBarEl.style.width = percent + '%';
    pBarTextEl.innerText = Math.round(percent) + '%';
    await sleep(20);
  }
}

progressBarExample();
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #999;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-bar div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #1f1f85;
  height: 30px;
  width: 0%;
}

.progress-bar span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Progressbar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div></div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```